# How to get full file directory in this command

Tags: c#, string, textinput

I write a tool using [Split and Join Files Tool](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/~hoangle/filesj/).

My code is:

```
foreach (String inputfiles in filename)
{
    String outputfiles = inputfiles.Remove(inputfiles.Length - 4);
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startinfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\sepdau\\Downloads\\Programs\\FFSJ.exe";
    startinfo.Arguments = "/C " + "-Task=Join " + "-Input=" + inputfiles + " -Output=" + outputfiles;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startinfo);
 }
 return 1;
```

With `filename` being a String Array of the files to Join.

When `inputfiles` name contains blank space e.g. `Lab 5.rar` it won't recieve full name but something like `C:\.....\Lab` instead.

How to get full path of `inputfiles`? Thank for helping :)

Comment: Did you try to enclose the file names into double quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Simply quote your filename:

```
startinfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C -Task=Join -Input=\"{0}\" -Output=\"{1}\""
    , inputfiles
    , outputfiles
    );
```

BTW, I'd rename `inputFiles` -> `inputFile`, and `filename` -> `filenames`.  Multiple files should have a plural-form name; each individual file should have a singular-form name.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the value with double quotes:

```
startinfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C -Task=Join -Input=\"{0}\" -Output=\"{1}\"", inputfiles, outputfiles);
```

Also introduced cleaner way to assign such a string.